# docker run -> command not found?

Tags: docker

I previously create an image with the command

docker build -t test .

but when I tried to run it with this command in the console

```
docker run -p 8080:9552 test
```

I get this error

```
docker run -p: command not found
```

any clue?

Comment: Are those spaces between docker, run, and -p? (Typed with the space bar and not copy/paste)

Comment: thanks for your message, what i discovered is that if I execute this in git bash is not working and I got this error, the solution was that I need to execute this command in the windows console, so weird.